# ntop make install error

Tags: linux, ntop

when i install ntop, both ./autogen.sh & make done, but in "make install" give this error:

```
ln: `icmpPlugin.so': File exists
make[2]: *** [icmpPlugin.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/ntop/compiles/ntop-3.3/plugins'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/ntop/compiles/ntop-3.3/plugins'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

?
excuse me for my bad english

Comment: Why don't you use your distributions package manager to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling packages as root ?

I'd suggest not doing that.

If ln says the destination file exists, why not rename/move it out of the way and try again ?

Comment: i'm root user, i renamed it, but error still there.